# Definition of opposite of a natural number

Tags: elementary-number-theory

**Some previous definitions**

1. $\forall m,n\in \mathbb{N}: m<p\iff \exists n\in \mathbb{N};\ n\ne 0:m+n=p$\
2. $\forall m,n\in \mathbb{N}: m\le n\iff m<n\ \veebar m=n$ where the symbol $\veebar$ means either...or... (not both).

One can prove that \begin{align*}\forall (m,p)\in \mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}:m< p\implies \exists!\  n\in \mathbb{N}; n\ne 0: m+n=p\tag{$i$}\end{align*} and \begin{align*}\forall (m,p)\in \mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}:m=p\implies \exists!\ n:m+n=p\tag{ii}\end{align*}

From $(i)$ and $(ii)$ we can define subtraction in $\mathbb{N}$ as follows:\begin{align*}\forall (m,p)\in \mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}\: m\le p\implies \Big(m+n=p\iff n=p-m\Big)\end{align*}So my question is **can we define the opposite of a natural number $n$, since we defined subtraction when $m\le n$, as follows**?$$\forall (m,n)\in \mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N};\ m\le n: m-n=-(n-m)$$

**Remark** By $\exists !$ I mean *There is a unique...*

Comment: This makes no sense.  Define precisely "opposite" in this context.

Comment: You need to introduce a new object $-n$ for each positive natural number, and define the operations $+$ and $\times$ on the new integers. There are many ways to do this, all somewhat involved, but if you search for something like "construction of Z" or "construction of the rational integers" you'll find some of the ways people usually do it.

Comment: In the context of natural numbers, you can’t really define $n-m$ when $n<m.$ The usual way to define integers is as $\mathbb N^2/\sim$ where $\sim$ is the equivalence relation $(a,b)\sim(c,d)\iff a+d=c+b.$. Basically, $(a,b)$ corresponds to  what we intuitively think of as the integer $a-b.$ Then you have to define addition and multiplication on this sets, using as intuition the formulae $$(a-b)+(c-d)=(a+c)-(b+d)\\(a-b)\cdot(c-d)=(ac+bd)-(bc+ad)$$

Comment: @Anonymous I thank you.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I thank you, as well.

Comment: If you don’t know about equivalence relations, think of the way we write $\frac12=\frac24.$ The equivalence relation is just saying “we are considering these as equal, even though they are written differently.”

Comment: This is a common construction for bigger sets of numbers. Construct a big set, and then define an equivalence relation. This is also how we define the rational numbers from the integers, and (if you use the Cauchy sequence method) the reals from the rationals.